# When I’m in my bed I move my pants because they are uncomfortable .In the process I accidentally become aroused and madhy comes out.What is the ruling

Tags: halal-haram

I want to know if this is haram. Please answer quick

when I’m in my bed I move my pants because they are uncomfortable .In the process I accidentally become aroused and madhy comes out.What is the ruling of this? I had no bad intentions

madhy is also known as precum